# Find the area of the region that is bounded by the given curve and lies in the specified sector. $r = e^{−θ/8}$, π/2 ≤ θ ≤ π

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the region that is bounded by the given curve and lies in the specified sector. $r = e^{−θ/8}$$\ ,\    π/2 ≤ θ ≤ π$

I know the formula is $\int_a^b \frac{1}{2} r^2 d\theta$

$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2} (e^{- \theta/8})^2 d\theta$

From this point I cannot integrate. Help!

My answer was $2e^{\frac{-\pi}{4}}(e^{\frac{\pi}{8}}-1)$

Comment: I do approve your answer. :)

Comment: That is not the answer though?

Comment: @Sunny **Hint:** \begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \exp \bigg(- \frac{\theta}{4} \bigg) d \theta &= \frac{1}{2} \bigg[ -4 \exp \bigg(- \frac{\theta}{4} \bigg) \bigg]_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}
\end{align}

Comment: That gives me the same answer I got before and that answer was wrong.

Comment: @Sunny Then the solution you have been given is wrong.

Comment: @Sunny Why do you say it is a wrong answer? What right answer have you been given?

Comment: I calculated $2e^{\frac{-\pi}{4}}(e^{\frac{\pi}{8}}-1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2} (e^{- \theta/8})^2 d\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} e^{- \theta/4} d\theta$$

Set $u=-\theta/4$, $\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}\theta}=\frac{-1}{4}$

$$=\frac{-4}{2}\int_{-\pi/8}^{-\pi/4} e^{u} du$$

$$=-2e^u|_{-\pi/8}^{-\pi/4} = 2e^{\frac{-\pi}{4}}(e^{\frac{\pi}{8}}-1)$$

You appear to have done it correctly.

Comment: Is there a different version? The computer program I am using refuses to accept the answer as is.

Comment: @Sunny It's possible that if the computer program was not written properly, it wants it in a very exact form. Try redistributing the $e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}$ and put that in.